# wsgen error on Netbeans

Tags: java, web-services, netbeans, ant

I'm trying to create Java web-service with Netbeans 8.2 and use it's tools to generate WSDL file. However it always fails with the error. After scouring the internet, apparently, it's because Netbeans does not put a space after WSGEN when generating the command.

And people who found it says to either enter the correct command manually or manually fix the error in ANT, however nowhere it's clarified how to actually do either of those things. And half-year old posts that can be found here, where people ask for this exact clarification, were never answered.

Therefore I want to try my luck now, can someone help fixing this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the way myself. Need to copy the faulty command from Netbeans output to cmd and fix the space. Before that - adding "wsgen" system path to **%SYSTEM%\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_102\bin** and then running the command from cmd. 
Guess Netbeans community really not much nowadays.

Answer (score 0):

I had the exact same problem and found fix at https://www.mkyong.com/webservices/jax-ws/deploy-jax-ws-web-services-on-tomcat/
apparently i did not create sun-jaxws.xml. When created and filled with required information everything worked perfectly